# Second Button in android is invisible

Tags: java, android

```
In the activity_main.xml is used 
- ScrollView
- LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout
```

For `TextView`, `RadioGroups`, `RadioButtons`, `EditText` and `Button`s.
 App was running normal till `resetButton` added. After this app runs but `resetButton` is invisible.
I think there is a mistake between layouts maybe I should use another combination of layouts, I don't know.
Thanks for any help!

```
   **activity_layout.xml**


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.allyouask.hungryforhistory.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                style="@style/welcomeMessage"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="Welcome to Hungry For History!\n         Let's get started!"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inputQuestion"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:text=" Who was the king of the Gods in Ancient Greece:"
                android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeMessage"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputAnswer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/inputQuestion"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inputAnswer"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Who was born in Ancient City Stagira, Greece?"/>


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/firstGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstQuestion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/firstLeftRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstGroupRadioButtons"
                android:text="Aristotle"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/firstRightRadioButton"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstGroupRadioButtons"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="Pythagoras"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstLeftRadioButton"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Who said in his last speech:With malice toward none;...let us strive on to finish the work we are in;to bind up the nation's wounds;into care for him who shall have borne the battle and for his widow and his orphans?"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/secondGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/secondQuestion"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/secondLeftRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/secondGroupRadioButtons"
                android:text="William McKinley"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/secondRightRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/secondGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="Abraham Lincoln"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thirdQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/secondLeftRadioButton"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Where the An Lushan Rebellion took place?"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/thirdGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thirdQuestion"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/thirdLeftRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thirdGroupRadioButtons"
                android:text="China"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/thirdRightRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thirdGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thirdLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="Thailand"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fourthQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thirdLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="Who was the most famous exemplar of absolute monarchy in France?"/>


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/fourthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fourthQuestion"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/fourthLeftRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fourthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:text="Louis XIV"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/fourthRightCheckBox"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fourthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourthLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="Michael I"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fifthQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fourthLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="When Alexander The Great lived?"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/fifthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/fifthQuestion"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/fifthLeftRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fifthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:text="330-323 BC"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/fifthRightRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fifthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fifthLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="336-323 BC"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sixthQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fifthLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="Where Albert Einstein studied?"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/sixthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sixthQuestion"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sixthLeftRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sixthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:text="University of Zurich"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sixthRightRadioButton"
                style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sixthGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sixthLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="University of Germany"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seventhQuestion"
                style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sixthLeftRadioButton"
                android:text="What was the main interest of Democritus?"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/seventhGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seventhQuestion"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/seventhLeftRadioButton"
                    style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/seventhGroupRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mathematics-Astronomy"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/seventhRightRadioButton"
                    style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/seventhGroupRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seventhLeftRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Philosophy-Psychology"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:background="@color/backgroundResetColor"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:text="Reset"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/submitButton"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    styles.xml
    <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#FFC107</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#E65100</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">#EF6C00</item>
        </style>

        <style name="welcomeMessage">
            <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
              <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
                <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#EF6C00</item>
        </style>

        <style name="QuestionsStyle">
            <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        </style>

        <style name="RadioButtonStyle">
         <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#FFAB00</item>
            <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>

        </style>

colors.xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FFC107</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E65100</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#EF6C00</color>

    <!-- Button Colors -->
<color name="backgroundColor">#EF6C00</color>
    <color name="backgroundResetColor">#FB8C00</color>
    <color name="textColor">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>     



        </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I get this Output. Are you want this or something else.
I have put your code inside this

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

         // your code here..

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

[image]'

**UpDate :**

you have to give `id` this way.. and check `layout_below` property to both `Button`.

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seventhGroupRadioButtons"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/submitButton"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:text="Reset"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: This Result I need But in my phone I can't see the reset button

Comment: I dont know if the problem is because I had a warning today and yesterday <android out of memory> I cant imagine something else

Comment: I just make a test and when the resetButton in somewhere else and not below the submitButton, ResetButton is fine

Comment: Can't figure it, I try what you suggest But again when resetButton is below Submit Button all designs gone, like color and text .

Comment: @ElenJ Where you have to put the `submitButton`.